# How can i save a REST Response to a PDF file?

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I have implemented the following method:

```
var client = new RestClient(string.Format(url, ponumber));
        var response = client.Get(
            new RestRequest(Method.GET)
                .AddHeader("accept", "application/json")
                .AddHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                .AddHeader("authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", myToken))
            );
```

The response is in Format "application/pdf". How can i convert that response to a PDF-File?

Comment: Are you asking how to write the response content to a file?

Comment: Yes. I haven't done this before.

Comment: Are you using RestSharp by any chance

Comment: Yes, i'm using RestSharp.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for helping out.